# Django template image.path.url does not work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a model with an `ImageField` called `photo`, but the html template gets an empty string when I use `photo.path.url`.

This is the model:

```
class Photograph(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='photos_of_user')
    photo = models.ImageField()
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos_of_album')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

This function returns the context I send to the template:

```
def populate_with_album_content(self, album_pk):
    album = Album.objects.get(id=album_pk)
    photos = album.photos_of_album.all()

    return { 'album': album, 'photos': photos }
```

And this is the html template:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
<div class="col-md-55">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="image view view-first">
            <img style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{photo.photo.path.url}}" alt="image" />
            <div class="mask">
                <p>Your Text</p>
                <div class="tools tools-bottom">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>{{ photo.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I know urls are well configured because I can see the pictures in the admin page, but, when I view the resulting page source, I can see that `src` are equal to empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`photo.photo.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FilePathField.path) will return file location on the server. `photo.path` doesn't have attribute `url` so `photo.photo.path.url` return empty string in template.  To get file url you should use [`photo.photo.url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) direclty:

```
<img style="width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{photo.photo.url}}" alt="image" />
```